# Displaying Multiple Results Array Search

Tags: java, arrays, search, date

I am searching for records that have the start date: [userinput], if it has any matches, that record will be displayed, the issue is that the nature of my program it is neccesary for ALL matches (there can be multiple on the same day) need to be somehow displayed.

This is what I have so far:

```
     public void searchDay() {
    String idInputString  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the Date you're searching for:");


       try {   
            for (int i = 0; i < orderID.length; i++) {
                if (idInputString.equals(startDate[i])) {

                    txtOrderID.setText(orderID[i]);
                    txtOrderForename.setText(customerForename[i]);
                    txtOrderSurname.setText(customerSurname[i]);

                    txtOrderAddress1.setText(address1[i]);
                    txtOrderAddress2.setText(address2[i]);
                    txtOrderTown.setText(town[i]);
                    txtOrderCounty.setText(county[i]);
                    txtOrderPost.setText(postCode[i]);
                    txtOrderCarModel.setText(carModel[i]);

                    txtOrderCarReg.setText(carReg[i]);
                    txtOrderStartDate.setText(startDate[i]);
                    txtOrderStartTime.setText(startTime[i]);

                    txtOrderSerial.setText(serialNum[i]);

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Order ID Doesn't Exist", "Error!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }

            }

      } catch (Exception e) { 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Order ID Doesn't Exist", "Error!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
       initFields();

   }
}
```

I get errors even when typing in a date I know exists.

I think the problem lies with the for loop. It counts the number of elements, not total records.

This is stored in "numberOfOrdersInArray" int variable.

But if I do:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOrdersInArray.length; i++) {
```

I get the error 'int cannot be dereferenced'

I hope I explained my problem well enough,

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.equals()` for string comparison **not** `==`. `==` checks against references, while `.equals()` actually compares the string characters. This is important.

**EDIT:**

```
//instead of a count, you could also use a boolean
for (int i = 0, count= 0; i < orderID.length; i++) {
                if (idInputString.equals(startDate[i])) {

                    txtOrderID.setText(orderID[i]);
                    txtOrderForename.setText(customerForename[i]);
                    txtOrderSurname.setText(customerSurname[i]);

                    txtOrderAddress1.setText(address1[i]);
                    txtOrderAddress2.setText(address2[i]);
                    txtOrderTown.setText(town[i]);
                    txtOrderCounty.setText(county[i]);
                    txtOrderPost.setText(postCode[i]);
                    txtOrderCarModel.setText(carModel[i]);

                    txtOrderCarReg.setText(carReg[i]);
                    txtOrderStartDate.setText(startDate[i]);
                    txtOrderStartTime.setText(startTime[i]);

                    txtOrderSerial.setText(serialNum[i]);
                    count++;
                } 
                if(i == orderID.length - 1 && count==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Order ID Doesn't Exist", "Error!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thank you, changed it to:
        if (idInputString.equals(startDate[i])) {
Still cannot find the record though.

Comment: please add your full code. i think you're looping over the wrong variable. either that or you're strings are actually different. either use breakpoints to debug your code or use print statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
 break; statement will be inside the if condition.

else {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Order ID Doesn't Exist", "Error!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
             //break;//Wrong HERE
}
```

Comment: yeah this could also be the answer depending on what speakon is exactly trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes that worked thank you! But now I have a new problem:

I enter the date, it searches, it displays the appropriate record.

BUT

It spams me with the error box repeatedly, even though it has been found.

Comment: obviously because the else box is being entered, since you're looping through. everytime the strings don't match, it shows the error.

Comment: @DhruvGairola Works perfectly now, thank you so much for your help. Now my second problem is, how do I display every record with this date, on one single GUI form? My knowledge of GUI's is awful. Thank you.

Comment: speakon, to show an error when nothing was shown, check out my updated answer. your second problem actually is a java problem more than a gui problem.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. I just have no idea how to display multiple results within one form.

Comment: you might have to create new widgets inside the loop each time the if statement is entered and add them to the enclosing panel. i think the enclosing panel can be programmed to have a certain layout. my swing knowledge is slightly rusty at this point though.

Comment: @DhruvGairola Thank you for all your help, I shall make a new thread for the problem of displaying multiple results. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer.  Why do you have a break statement? As soon as something doesn't match in your if clause it breaks from the for loop (break statements do nothing for if else statements).

But also I'm confused about what you said here:

> "I think the problem lies with the for loop. It counts the number of elements, not total records.
>
> This is stored in "numberOfOrdersInArray" int variable."

Is numberOfOrdersInArray an int variable?  In that case why are you using numberOfOrdersInArray.length?  The .length is a variable that is held by arrays which is why it works if you have arrayName.length.  But if numberOfOrdersInArray is just a counter int variable, then use it by itself so it looks like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOrdersInArray; i++) {
```

Comment: Idiotic coding on my behalf, it's all been cleared up now.

Just the last issue of:

"atDhruvGairola Works perfectly now, thank you so much for your help. Now my second problem is, how do I display every record with this date, on one single GUI form? My knowledge of GUI's is awful. Thank you."

Left to sort, thanks for your input.